# Intel Graphics card unable to compile shaders

Tags: emulation, graphics-card, dolphin-emulator

While trying to load Mario Kart Double Dash on a copy of the Dolphin Emulator running on an ASUS laptop with an Intel Graphics card running Windows 10, I got the following error message:

```
Failed to compile vertex shader:

C:\Users\[my username]\Documents\Dolphin\Emulator\Dump\bad_vs_0000.txt

Debug info (Intel, Intel(R) HD Graphics 520, 4.4.0 - Build 21.20.16.4550):

ERROR: 1:8: 'std140' : syntax error syntax error
```

After clicking OK, I heard sound, but couldn't see anything in the emulation window and got errors until I closed Dolphin.

Comment: there may be useful info in that dump

Comment: have you tried updating graphic drivers?

Answer (score 3):

Use Direct3D instead of OpenGL.

1. From the main menu, open the **Graphics** menu.
2. There, under **Basic**, change the backend to "Direct3D 11".
3. Click "Close" and start the game.

Answer (score 0):

Delete `[os_drive]\Users\[username]\Documents\Dolphin Emulator`. If you want to keep anything there, put it somewhere else as backup.

Surprisingly worked for me.